# I am trying to echo out array values that will be sent in email

Tags: php

Hello I am working on a project and I have values that are stored in an array, my next step is to then put it in a message that will be mailed.  My problem is when I try to test it out by echoing it just tells me "Array"

Code:

Loop I'm using

```
for($j =0; $j< $i; $j +=1 ){
        $firstname = $firstnamearray[$j];

    echo "
        $firstname 

";
}
```

array stored

```
if ($status == "Open"){

                $firstnamearray[] = array($i => $firstname);
                $lastnamearray[] = array($i => $lastname);
                $statusarray[] = array($i => $status);
                $i +=1;
        }
```

Thank you for your time let me know if you need anything else!

Comment: Yo should share `array` structure.

Comment: This means that `$firstnamearray[$j]` is an Array - do a `var_dump($firstnamearray)` and see what's the output - then post it here.

Comment: Figured it out thanks to @donald but thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems that $firstnamearray[$j] is an array too

try this

```
for($j =0; $j< $i; $j +=1 ){
    $firstname = $firstnamearray[$j];

echo "
    $firstname[0]

    ";
}
```

too see what is stored into $fistname

```
  for($j =0; $j< $i; $j +=1 ){
    $firstname = $firstnamearray[$j];
    var_dump($firstname);die;
  }
```

Comment: used .= to keep adding to message file.

Answer (score 0):

[print_r](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) will pretty print all the values/nested structures in the array.

```
print_r(firstnamearray);
```

Alternatively if you wish to store what is printed as a string

```
$foo = print_r($firstnamearray, TRUE);
```

If you're writing emails programmatically be sure to map any entities such as & or > using [htmlentities](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php).

```
$foo = htmlentities(print_r($firstnamearray, TRUE));
```

Comment: you missed $ sign in array variable

Comment: @Tiberiu-IonuțStan Kind of out of scope as he's only using echo at this stage to debug his code, but added some information anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($array as $key => $value){
  echo "#".$key." - ".$value;
}
```

The foreach statement will loop on each item of your table
http://php.net/manual/fr/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: what if you have nested arrays?

Comment: foreach is cleanest, but yes, it does the same ;)

Answer (score 0):

For mime **text/plain**:

`echo var_export($_SERVER, true);`

For mime **text/html**:

`echo highlight_string("<?php ".var_export($_SERVER, true));`

Comment: Why `var_export`? He need to display all array data using var_dump or print_r.

Comment: **Note: highlight_string will also do the necessary html special characters escaping.**

Comment: @qeremy Two reasons: consistency with highlight_string output, which would highlight only valid PHP code; it gives back valid PHP code, which is way much more readable than anything else.

Comment: I just asked that Why var_export?

Comment: Jezuz, why downvote? This applies to both e-mails and web pages, fully, and is the best solution possible. And not leaving a comment is just vandalism.